# Blackberry UI Programming Resources

Tags: user-interface, blackberry

I am new with Blackberry programming and Java in general.  I do have previous experience with C, C++, VB, and quite a few others.  However, this is my first foray into the Java world.

I have found lots of information on MIDP classes, but would rather use native RIM API whenever possible, especially for UI elements.  Specifically, I am looking at using the MIDP form element to set up my screen layout, but do not know if that is the best option.  Or is there a Blackberry specific solution to this?  If I do use the MIDP form element, will it render like a native Blackberry app?  Or will it look like an MIDP app?

Also, does anyone have a good resource for BB specific tutorials and samples?  The hardest part of starting out seems to be the lack of newbie information out there.

Answer (score 5):

There is a guy who post here who runs a good intro blog on using the RIM UI APIs

http://www.thinkingblackberry.com

MIDP will look like MIDP.

There is also a reasonable set of links here.

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/board/message?board.id=java_dev&thread.id=13264

and that's also a support forum as it were.

Answer (score 4):

The Blackberry developer zone has a lot of good tutorials and examples on the RIM API:

http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/learningresources/

Answer (score 1):

Only with tremendous effort it might be possible to mix BlackBerry UI components with MIDP components.

You should stick to native BlackBerry components anyway. They are more sophisticated, easier to use, and future proof. Moreover, the look better on BlackBerry devices.